# Is there a way to lower the bluetooth signal strength, on a Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth

I've set up the bluetooth and Works as intended, but the signal strength is much more than I need it to be. I need the range to be half of what it is right now.

**Update**:

Found a solution using the [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) library to handle the bluetooth pairing part and a [beacon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FC5FMHW) that emits a constant bluetooth signal.
This [guide](https://makersportal.com/blog/2017/12/31/using-raspberry-pi-hm-10-and-bluepy-to-develop-an-ibeacon-mesh-network-part-1) and the library [documentation](https://ianharvey.github.io/bluepy-doc/) helped *a lot*.

Comment: What problem is the power being higher than it needs to be causing?

Comment: I only want it to pick up devices if they are very close to the Pi. As it is, it pickups devices at a close and long distance.

Comment: Could you achieve the same thing by doing [distance estimation using the RSSI](https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/bluetooth-le-distance-determination-using-rssi/) value of the found device? The device doing the discovery can [filter on RSSI](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt#n49) value

Comment: `pickups devices at a close and long distance` you would have to adjust the transmit signal strength of those devices

Comment: @jsotola Right. And, how do I do that?

Comment: @ukBaz That's actually a very good idea. I'll look into that.

Comment: @Jcorretjer that's just it, you can't adjust the transmit signal of other devices ... all you can do is to ignore them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Raspberry Pi the Bluetooth stack is BlueZ. In very recent (newer versions that ship with RPi OS) there is a new experimental feature to change the Tx Power of advertisements.

This is documented in the following document (Search for "power")

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager.rst

To evaluate this functionality you will have to build and install a newer version of BlueZ with experimental features enabled.

Comment: How would I build/install with experimental features enabled?

Comment: By using the `--enable-experimental` flag during compilation. See [README](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/README) for more information

Comment: Even though it wasn't a straight answer it did lead me to find my own answer.

Comment: @Jcorretjer glad you have solved your problem. You could write up your solution and then accept your own answer as that way we all learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use WiFi (or the WiFi signal is also very strong) you could reduce the effective radio range by shielding the antenna. Putting the Pi inside a tin cookie/tea box (with the lid partially open) should do the trick. If the range becomes too short, open the lid some more. A tin can should also do if you don't mind the looks.

Just make sure you don't let the metal touch the PCB or the GPIO pins.